# Save byte[] to image with FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android, image, server, fileoutputstream

I send with my Android device a picture to my Java server. I do this with a byte[]. Then I want to store it at my server. But this doesn't work right. The file has the right size, but when I want to open it, windows says: The file can't be opened. What's wrong?

```
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("./images/"+IDfromPost+".png");
     fos.write(buffer);
     fos.close();
```

buffer is my byte[], IDfromPost an integer.

By the way. I display the length of the byte array at my phone and the server and both are the same.

Comment: You should show all relevant client and server code. Open the file in wordpad to see if it starts with .PNG.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problems with Android, you have to check how you decode the `byte[]` in your server to convert it to a ImageFile.

If you want more help, you have to update the post with the specification of you server.

Regards.

Comment: Set the corrent word _convert_ does not change the fact that there is  lack of information to answer.